# CSS hover not working on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am trying to make a really simple CSS hover. It works fine in IE, Edge, Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work for Safari (9.1) on Mac.

Have searched the internet and Stack Overflow for a fix, but no joy.

Found this simple example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Pixelizm/pen/ICpKv/). That works on safari.

BUT: If i take that code, put it into a plain html document and serve it from Azure, it does not work on hover. You have to click on/off the element for the bit that should show on hover to appear. Oddly, if I use the web inspector and toggle the hover state, it works. Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        #thumbnail {
            display: block;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }

            #thumbnail:hover + #title {
                display: block;
            }

        #title {
            display: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #000000;
            text-align: center;
            width: 130px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

    <a id="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/0066ff/fff"></a>
    <div id="title">filename.jpg 1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I then created a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CmsD2xfcGKQ0cGY6omwt) to see if something extra was going on in codepen. The plunk also works in Safari on Mac.

What do I need to do to get it working in a standard page please?

Comment: This is working on Safari 9..1.1 (OS X 10.11.5).  I've tested the CodePen, the Plnkr link, and the example code you pasted.

Comment: Just looking to update the os/browser now....

Comment: Thanks @RobertC. The answer was to update Mac OS X to 10.11.5. I'm still not sure what to do to avoid people hitting the issue in the first place. Obviously it would be nice if people kept their software updated, but it's pretty unrealistic to expect them to.

Comment: @HockeyJ I'm about 99.9% sure it wasn't the version of OSX that was the problem. Chances are it was a browser caching or configuration error on your end. Safari (and therefore Mac operating systems) has supported `:hover` for years and years.

Comment: We have 3 (now 2) macs it's not working on. Have just given up and used angular ng-mouseenter/mouseleave instead. Have been clearing the cache, but it could well be caching or config. The hacky alternative is working on all, so going to have to go with that. Bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your codepen example and even created a HTML file with the contents above and tested it again in Safari 9.1.1 - all working absolutely fine.

You may find the issue is Safari caching your content from Azure, can you clear the web browser cache and retry the issue?

Perhaps there's a cache on Azure that needs clearing also?

Comment: thanks for looking into it. It turned out I needed to update OS X (see comment above for details). Doesn't provide a fix for all users unfortunately. Seems it was a buggy version of OSX/Safari. Have upvoted for your effort of looking into it.